# Click one Panel, Hide other Panels - Ext JS

Tags: extjs, hide, panel, show

I have three separate buttons with controllers. When one of the buttons is clicked, a panel is created and displayed (with animation). Here's what one of my controllers looks like:

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Prod_Select', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    init: function() {
        this.control({
            '#prod_select': {
                click: this.prodSelect
            }
        });
    },

    prodSelect: function() {
        var subPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            width: 200,
            height: 160,
            html: '<center><p class="sub_panel_text "> Link <br /> Link <br /> Link </p> </center>',
            bodyStyle: 'background:#010a4d',
            border:false,
            floating: true,
            shadow: false,
            style: 'opacity: 0;',
            x: 770,
            y: 75,
            cls: 'sub_panel'
        });
        subPanel.show();
        subPanel.animate({
            duration: 1000,
            to: {
                opacity: .6,
                x: 800,
                y: 75
            }
        }); 
        console.log('Clicked Prod');
    }
});
```

This works just fine, but currently I can click one button x amount of times, and it will create x amount of panels. What I want out of this controller, however, is to create only a single panel from a click AND hide any other panel (with fade out) that may displayed already out of the three.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a property to the subPanel so it can be easily selected using ComponentQuery, then iterate through the query's results and hide the other panels.

```
var subPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
   someCustomProperty: 'someCustomValue',
   ...    
});

var allPanels = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel[someCustomProperty="someCustomValue"]');

Ext.Array.each(allPanels, function(panel) {
   if (panel === subPanel) {
      //show it
   } else {
      //hide it
   }
});
```